# How to dynamically convert row to column in MySQL and display the results in Swing

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am trying to dynamically convert rows to columns in MySQL and display the results in Java/Swing.

The code I use to convert rows to columns, is the following

```
SET @cols = NULL;
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(Name = ''',
      Name, ''', Amount , NULL)) AS ', '''', Name , '''')
  ) INTO @cols
FROM table1;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT 
  Date, ', @cols , ', SUM(Amount) AS Total 
FROM table1
GROUP BY Date;');

prepare stmt 
FROM @sql;

execute stmt;
```

Although I got the results in MySQL, I don't know how use that code and display the results in Java Swing.

Comment: Please clarify your question. -- Do you want to [invoke a mysql stored procedure](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/calling-mysql-stored-procedures-from-jdbc/) and [show the result in a Swing JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815400/retrieving-data-from-jdbc-database-into-jtable) ?

Comment: yes i want to invoke this mysql procedure and show it in jtable, can you guide me with example? please

Comment: If you want to transpose the results, I think you must transpose the TableModel  in Java instead of "Dynamically convert row to column"

Comment: `and show it in jtable,` - well there are plenty of examples in the forum and on the web that show how to do this. You can start by searching this forum using `JTable` and `ResultSet` to find examples showing how to create a `TableModel` with data found in a ResultSet. This is how you solve many problems. You just pick a couple of keywords and do a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Creating a Stored Procedure with a Prepared Statement**

First, you must [create a stored procedure using a prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895383/mysql-prepare-statement-in-stored-procedures). I have not tested your code, but the stored procedure can be created using code like the following.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS execSql;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE execSql () 
BEGIN

  SET @sql = CONCAT( ...

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

**Invoking a MySQL Stored Procedure using JDBC**

JDBC offers a `CallableStatement` class you can use to invoke stored procedures. You may check a tutorial for [Calling MySQL Stored Procedures from JDBC](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/calling-mysql-stored-procedures-from-jdbc/).

```
// use CALL with the name of the stored procedure
String query = "{CALL execSql()}";

// use CallableStatement to obtain the ResultSet
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(query)
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

**Showing the result in a Swing JTable**

To display the data, you may create a `TableModel` with the ResultSet. There are many classes/libraries that you can use to fill a TableModel with the resultset (such as [this DbUtils](http://technojeeves.com/index.php/22-resultset-to-tablemodel) or [this JDBCTableModel](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/swinghks_hack24/index.html?page=2)).

```
// execute the query
String query = "{CALL execSql()}";
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(query)
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

// fill the TableModel with the results
TableModel normalTableModel = DBUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs);

// create the Swing Table
JTable swingTable = new JTable (transposedTableModel);
```

**Transposing a TableModel**

Sometimes you want to transpose (convert rows to columns) the results ot a Query. Although MySQL [does not support PIVOT/UNPIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392956/sql-how-to-transpose), you can transpose the Swing's TableModel. I think transposing the TableModel is the better (simpler) alternative.

Basically, you can [create a TableModel wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667550/java-visualization-how-to-transpose-a-jtable-in-java) that transpose the results. You may check the [Spring TableModel](https://www.javatips.net/api/spring-shell-master/src/main/java/org/springframework/shell/table/TableModel.java) and the [JideSoft TransposeTableModel](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/grid/TransposeTableModel.html). The code for a `TransposedTableModel` may be something like the following...

```
public TransposedTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

  private TableModel innerTableModel;

  public TransposedTableModel(TableModel innerTableModel) {
     this.innerTableModel = innerTableModel;
  }

  @Override
  public int getRowCount() {
     return innerTableModel.getColumnCount();
  }

  @Override
  public   int getColumnCount() {
     return innerTableModel.getRowCount();
  }

  Override
  public   Object getValue(int row, int column) {
     return innerTableModel.getValue(column, row);
  }
};
```

Then, you can use a "normal" SQL, [fill a TableModel with the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620448/most-simple-code-to-populate-jtable-from-resultset) and the use the transposed TableModel.

```
stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table1");

TableModel normalTableModel = DBUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs);
TableModel transposedTableModel = new TransposedTableModel(normalTableModel);

JTable swingTable = new JTable (transposedTableModel);
```